# How to set append variable on condition in laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing project in Laravel. I have model named 'User.php' and here I want to set $appends variable depends on condition.
In database I have stored values in key attribute format.
eg:

- I have table named 'user' which contains basic info like name, email and mobile number.
- Other table named as 'user_attributes_master' which contains columns like 'avatar', 'theme', etc.
- and other table named as 'user_attribute_values' which contains columns like 'id', 'user_id' and 'att_id'(which is a primary key of user_attributes_master table)

user.php looks like

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
protected $appends = ['avatar_photo'];

public function profile_attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Access\User\UserProfileAttributes::class,config('access.user_attribute_values_table'),'user_id','user_attribute_id')->withPivot('value', 'active')->withTimestamps();
    }

/**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatarPhotoAttribute()
    {
        $avatar = $this->profile_attributes()->where('user_attributes_master.id',7)->first()->avatar_path;
        return $avatar;

    }
}
```

Here I get avatar_path attribute to every record which is append variable I have set to profile.php model. How to get this to only 'avatar' col of profile.php. How can I set this appends variable.

attribute model conatins code,

```
protected $appends = ['avatar_path','theme_path'];

public function getAvatarPathAttribute()
    {
            return $this->pivot->value != null ? config('app.url').'/'.config('profile.images.user_images'). "/" . $this->pivot->user_id ."/" . config("profile.images.avatar")."/".$this->pivot->value : '';

    }
```

Here I dont want 'avatar_path' for every attribute.

Comment: You want to change the attributes in `$appends` depending on some condition?

Comment: yes if my attribute value contains avatar then only I want full path in that object. right now it exists with every attribute in the object

Answer (score 2):

You can use `appends()` to dynamically add attributes to `$appends`. Try this:

```
$attributes->where('pivot.value', '!=', null)->each->appends('avatar_path');
```

Answer (score 0):

rename: `protected $appends = ['avatar_photo'];`

to : `'protected $appends = ['avatarphoto'];'`

Comment: I have edited my question now you might get I have done